# Add JS function to inner html field?

Tags: javascript, html, time, user-input, innerhtml

Beginner JavaScript Practice.
I am creating a simple page where the user can input a number of minutes and it will return the hours and minutes.
Ex: 500 minutes = 8hrs 20mins

I have an input field for the user to input a number of minutes (works perfectly fine on it’s own)

I have a function that takes the total number of minutes and returns the equivalent hours:minutes (works perfectly fine on it’s own as well)

The issue I’m having is connecting these two sections of code to work together. So that the user may input a number and minutes, then run the function, and return the hours and minutes equivalent the the number of minutes they gave.

Any help would ge greatly appreciated! As I mentioned, I am very new to JavaScript (:

```js
let form = document.getElementById("form")

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault() // prevents form from auto-submitting

  let userMinutes = document.getElementById("minutes").value
  // .value = extract the value the user has inputted 
  // console.log(userMinutes)
});

// JavaScript function to convert minutes —> hours and minutes
function timeConvert(n) {
  let num = n;

  let hours = num / 60;
  let rhours = Math.floor(hours);

  let minutes = (hours - rhours) * 60;
  let rminutes = Math.round(minutes);

  return num + " minutes =" + rhours + " hour(s) and " + rminutes + " minute(s)."

  console.log(timeConvert(n));
};
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="minutes" name="minutes" placeholder="minutes" required>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no need for a `form` here since you won't be submitting any form data anywhere. And, because there's no need for a `form`, you won't use the `submit` event or `preventDefault()` either. Instead, you just need a regular `button` to trigger the operation.

See additional comments inline below:

```js
// Get your element references once rather that every time the function runs
// And, when you do get your references, just get a reference
// to the element, not any property of the element
// so that in case you need to access the element at some
// future point in time, you don't have to query the document
// for the same element again.
let userMinues = document.getElementById("minutes");
let result = document.querySelector("#result");

// No need for a separate function to do the work.
// Just do it in the click handler
document.querySelector("input[type='button'").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  let num = userMinues.value;

  let hours = num / 60;
  let rhours = Math.floor(hours);

  let minutes = (hours - rhours) * 60;
  let rminutes = Math.round(minutes);

  // Event handlers shouldn't return anything because
  // you have no place to return the value to. Instead
  // populate an empty element that serves as a placeholder
  // for the answer. Also, don't use .innerHTML when you 
  // can avoid it because it has performance and security
  // implications.
  result.textContent = num + " minutes =" + rhours + " hour(s) and " + rminutes + " minute(s)."
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="minutes" name="minutes" placeholder="minutes" required>
<input type="button" value="Go!">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I think there are too many (valid) suggestions without a clear explanation as to what the actual problem is. I think a form is much better so the user can submit the form using enter from the text field.

Comment: @RuanMendes Really, what about the comments describing that an event handler shouldn't return anything didn't you follow?

Comment: Your main statement (First, there's no need for a form here) in your response is a suggestion. It's not the answer. As I mentioned, I think it's a poor suggestion. You're forcing me to read a lot of code instead of giving a simple explanation as to why the OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: @RuanMendes The main text of the answer indicates that there is a bunch of unnecessary code that should be removed (not sure why you think that is a poor suggestion). And, with that extraneous code removed, the answer provides clear commentary on what is being done and why.

Comment: Their event handler did not return anything. Look at my answer, it clearly states what they were doing wrong. Only changed one line of their code. If you want to make suggestions, it's clearer to make them separately. There is no need to inline the handler and there's no need to remove the form, those are your personal preferences.

Comment: @RuanMendes An event handler can't return anything. There's no callable context to return it to (which is explained in the answer).

Comment: *There is no need to inline the handler and there's no need to remove the form, those are your personal preferences.* <-- Supplying the callback function inline is not only acceptable, but it is extremely common. Unless you'll need to remove the handler later, there's no reason not to do it (as you did in your answer). And, removing the `form` and `preventDefault()` isn't a preference, unless you consider it a standard to include unnecessary code in y our solutions.

Comment: *you're not suggesting anything (too) harmful.* <-- I haven't posted anything at all that is, in any way, harmful. In fact, my answer removes the harmful code that was in the OPs code.

Comment: You don't know the OP doesn't want to use that function somewhere else. Also, I explained the benefit of leaving the form in but you don't care.

Comment: By removing the form, you made accessibility worse since keyboard users expect to trigger default action by using enter. Just saying, stick to the question the OP asked instead of posting your opinions.

Comment: *I think a form is much better so the user can submit the form using enter from the text field.* <-- That is your preference to handle the accessibility. Pressing ENTER to invoke the callback can also be implemented without triggering events and then cancelling them.

Comment: Yes, it can but it's way trickier. Why not use native support instead of fiddling with keycodes that are different per OS? Again, I'm just saying most of your changes were not necessary to get the OP's code working. My answer shows that a single-line change made their code work.

Comment: `event.key` doesn't rely on codes that vary. What I'm saying is that working code in no way means good or correct code. I am an educator and my decades of experience (especially with new coders) is that bad habits should be broken before they can set in. I always answer questions here with additional suggestions and history has shown me that those answers are overwhelmingly received positively.  Your single line change makes the code "work", but it still has many performance, security, standards and scalability issues.

Comment: You did not fix any security, standards or scalability issues. Having a separate function is not an issue, it's your preference. Not having a form is also your personal preference.

Comment: Getting element references just once outside of the callback instead of every time the callback fires improves performance. Setting the element variable to the element, rather than a property of the element makes scaling easier and helps in performance (you don't have to re-query the DOM for an element reference you've already queried for). Avoiding `.innerHTML` is absolutely a performance and security best practice. These are not my "preferences", they are best-practices that are widely known and accepted.

Comment: The removal of the second function and the form simplifies the code quite a bit and with a new coder, it's best to start correctly, but as simple as possible.

Comment: "Getting element references just once outside of the callback instead of every time the callback fires improves performance" => Premature optimization, your personal preference. The OP was not even using `innerHTML`, they were just trying to log.

Comment: You’re absolutely right. I personally prefer to consider performance when writing code. Also, let’s not confuse what I did with what is generally considered poor practice, which is the optimization of how code is written to make it shorter. Coding to take into account performance is something we all should do. Have you ever gotten or given a code review? You seem to want to dispute established standards and best practices and call them my personal preferences.

Comment: You seem to believe your personal preferences are best practices. Kind of silly for you to ask if I have ever reviewed code considering I told you I have also been programming for over 25 years. The OP was not asking for a review, they were asking to figure out why their code wasn't working.

Comment: If you’ve programmed for 25 years and believe what I’m saying is personal preference and not well documented best practices and never had someone point these things out to you in a code review, says more about your experience and less about my preferences. Ever heard of Doug Crockford? Probably not. Merry Christmas and good luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling `timeConvert()` from your event handler. Also, you were trying to `console.log` after returning from `timeConvert()` which means that even if you called it, it wouldn't log anything.

```js
let form = document.getElementById("form")

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault() // prevents form from auto-submitting

  let userMinutes = document.getElementById("minutes").value
  // THE FIX
  console.log(timeConvert(userMinutes));
});

function timeConvert(n) {
  let num = n;

  let hours = num / 60;
  let rhours = Math.floor(hours);

  let minutes = (hours - rhours) * 60;
  let rminutes = Math.round(minutes);

  return num + " minutes =" + rhours + " hour(s) and " + rminutes + " minute(s)."
  };
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="minutes" name="minutes" placeholder="minutes" required>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to separate your calculation/logic things from the rest.  Try to get a section of code to do ONE thing.

I left your form as a form but it might also just be some elements with click handlers etc.

Here I converted your function to return an object, called that then used that object that was returned to show the values.

The  whole display part might also be placed in another function but I left that to you to do that as a learning exercise here.

```js
let form = document.getElementById("form");
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevents form from auto-submitting
  let userMinutes = document.getElementById("minutes").value;
  // just get an object with the values from a function then use them:
  let timeThings = timeConvert(userMinutes);
  /* can do this one of two ways: string or a template literal */
  //  const showMe = timeThings.entered + " minutes = " + timeThings.hours + " hour(s) and " + timeThings.minutes + " minute(s).";
  /* using a template literal:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals */
  const showMe = `${timeThings.entered} minutes = ${timeThings.hours} hour(s) and ${timeThings.minutes} minute(s).`;
  console.log(showMe);
});

function timeConvert(minutesEntered) {
  let hours = minutesEntered / 60;
  let rhours = Math.floor(hours);
  let minutes = (hours - rhours) * 60;
  let rminutes = Math.round(minutes);
  return {
    entered: minutesEntered,
    minutes: rminutes,
    hours: rhours
  };
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="number" id="minutes" name="minutes" placeholder="minutes" required>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You've used template literals and introduced using an object to wrap the results, without explaining what those things are. The OP has stated that they are a beginner and neither of those syntaxes really address the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use your function as an event handler which is a function that is invoked when a registered [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) is triggered. You can use the [HTMLFormElement](https://javascript.info/form-elements) interface for terse syntax and solid control over all [form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#form-associated_content) within the `<form>`.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Reference <form>
const form = document.forms.form;
/**
 * Bind <form> to "submit" event 
 * When "submit" event is triggered, 
 * invoke event handler convertTime(event)
 */
form.addEventListener('submit', convertTime);

/**
 * Event handler passes event object by default
 * Stop default "submit" behavior of <form>
 *
 * Reference all <input> and <output> within <form>
 * Reference <input>
 * Reference <output>
 * 
 * Convert the value of <input> from String to Number
 * (Next 4 lines are calculations)
 * 
 * Assign the value of <output> as a template literal with the 
 * calculated values interpolated within.
 */
function convertTime(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const io = this.elements;
  const dataMin = io.minutes;
  const dataRes = io.result;

  let min = parseInt(dataMin.value);
  let hrs = min / 60;
  let rhrs = Math.floor(hrs);
  let mins = (hrs - rhrs) * 60;
  let rmins = Math.round(mins);

  dataRes.value = `${min} minutes = ${rhrs} hour(s) and ${rmins} minute(s).`
};
```

```css
:root {
  font: 300 2ch/1.15 "Segoe UI"
}

input,
output {
  display: block;
  min-height: 1.15rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <!-- Use [type="number"] instead of [type="text"] -->
  <input id="minutes" name="data" type="number" placeholder="Minutes..." required>
  <!-- Use an output element to display results -->
  <output id="result" name="data"></output>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Why all these rewrites when one line can be changed to make the OP's code work?

Comment: `document.forms.form` is a non-standard, legacy approach for querying the DOM using the BOM. Instead, `document.querySelector("form")` or `document.getElementById("form")` would be the standardized way to go.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I can't find any references that say HTMLFormElement interface is non-standard. I'll gladly add that in but I'd like a link.

Comment: Let's add that if the form has an ID, the ID becomes a global variable, another shady way of doing it. That is actually supported but I avoid it; it's always clearer to just use `document.getElementById("form")`

Comment: I didn’t say that the form element interface was non-standard. I said your technique for getting to the interface is (document.forms). The forms array of the document object is from the browser object model, which is non-standard.

Comment: So legacy properties like `.frames`, and `.links` are non-standard as well?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I finally get your point, being that `.forms` is a BOM property, there is no standard for how a browser implements said properties. Being that `.forms` is as old as dirt and still not on the deprecated "chopping block", it's use isn't inefficient and/or unsafe (AFAIK).

Comment: Just because something isn’t depicted does not in any way mean that the item isn’t inefficient or unsafe. Plus you really can’t depreciate something that was non standard in the first place. Non standard items should always be avoided because of non standard results.

Comment: Yes, forms, links, frames are also from the BOM. And anything with an ID (regardless of what code you use to get its reference) will cause global properties of the window object to be created.

Comment: Thank you, for taking the time to explain your reasons for discourse. I learned a few things I must've slept through in college. 

Answer (score -1):

There you go

```
<input id="minutes" type="number">
<button onclick="calc()">calc</button>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
    function timeConvert(n) {
        let num = n;
        
        let hours = num / 60;
        let rhours = Math.floor(hours);
        
        let minutes = (hours - rhours) * 60;
        let rminutes = Math.round(minutes);
        
        
        return num + " minutes =" + rhours + " hour(s) and " + rminutes + " minute(s)."
    }
    
    function calc() {
      const result = timeConvert(parseInt(document.querySelector('#minutes').value))
      
      document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = result
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A good answer is one that not only shows working code but explains what the problem was in the first place and how/why the solution presented overcomes the problems. A code dump with "there you go" isn't a good answer.

Comment: @elirsanc It may "work", but it has several problems with performance, security, conformance to standards, and scalability. Check my answer.